# Question about the Curl of a Vector Field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, vector-fields, spherical-coordinates

[image]

Sorry if this question seems trivial, I am new to the material. So while I was studying, I ran into this problem.

I originally thought that the problem is easy. First, I found the curl of E which I found to be $\vec{X}=-5i-6xk$.

Then, I found $x$ by using the spherical coordinates given to us like this: $x = 2\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})\cos(\pi) = -\sqrt{3}$. So I end up with $\vec{X}=-5i+6\sqrt{3}k$.

So we simply find $X_r$ by squaring all components to find that $X_r=\sqrt{133}$.

But it seems like I'm wrong because it says that the solution is $1.732$.

I tried solving it again to see if I did anything wrong but I can't seem to realise my mistake.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please write the question out in latex, and welcome to MSE!

Comment: The magnitude of vector is not $X_r$.. $X_r$ is only the radial direction, the vector may be pointed away from this radial direction

Comment: While you have a mistake as pointed out, the official solution does not seem correct either.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that $$X_r^2\ne X_x^2+X_y^2+X_z^2$$
Instead $$X_r=\vec X\cdot\hat r$$ where
$$\hat r=\begin{pmatrix}\sin\theta\cos\phi\\\sin\theta\sin\phi\\\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$